# Embedding a view from a page with php

Tags: views, theming

I need to put three view blocks next to each other on a page. Therefore, I thought i could put some php code in a new page and manually put them next to each other with DIVs.

The problem is that I can't seem to output the views block.

I have tried multiple things:

```
//load the view by name
$view = views_get_view('woensdag');
//output the view
//var_dump($view);
--> this returns the view, so it is being loaded

$view_name = 'woensdag';

views_embed_view($view_name, 'default');
--> outputs nothing

views_get_view_result($view_name, 'block');
--> outputs nothing

echo views_embed_view('woensdag', $display_id = 'block') 
--> outputs nothing
```

The delta  name of the view is woensdag-block_1, I have tried that as well.

Any ideas? I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: You can add blocks created with the Views module from the user interface. Check you are logged in with a user account which has the permssion to see the view, since [`view_embed_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) uses `$view->access()` to verify the user can access the view.

Comment: Does your view return something if you test it in Views UI? does your view expect arguments? if yes - you will have pass them to views_embed_view as well (or provide a default value).

Comment: Yes it does. In fact, I have temporarily solved it, just by adding the view to the content pane and restricting it to one page only. Still I thought I should be able to render a view from php.

Answer (score 0):

```
views_embed_view($view_name, 'default');
// does not work because you need to print/echo the result. eg.
print views_embed_view($view_name, 'default');

views_get_view_result($view_name, 'block');
//does not work because the function returns an array (and you aren't even trying to print the array anyway)

echo views_embed_view('woensdag', $display_id = 'block')
// Trying to set a variable in a function call? It probably would have worked like this:
echo views_embed_view('woensdag', 'block')
```